# XQuartz: user / environment when executing xinit? (XMonad, xmodmap, etc.)

Tags: x11, xquartz

I'm running XMonad with XQuartz on an 11,3 Macbook Prop Retina. My `.xinitrc` looks as follow:

```
[[ -f ~/.Xdefaults ]] && xrdb -load ~/.Xdefaults
export LANG="en_CA.UTF-8"
xmodmap /Users/xxxxxxx/.xmodmarc
cd $HOME
/Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Haskell/bin/xmonad
```

I've noticed that both the `LANG` export and the `xmodmap` are being called, but their effects are not persisting. If I throw some `env >> tmp.txt` in there I can see that it's a different environment than when I finally reach a terminal, and I suspect perhaps even a different user that is calling `xinit`.

**My Questions**

- what user or environment is actually calling `xinit` when you startup XQuartz?
- where is the appropriate place to put `xmodmap` so that it's called once, and only once, when XQuartz is started?
- How do I get the `LANG` set once, and only once, as an environment variable when I start XQuartz (I need it for unicode support)

Thank you!

Comment: you have `cd $HOME` in your `~/.xinitrc`?  If yes, then remove that line.  Also, place `exec` in front of your call to `xmonad`, like this: `exec .../bin/xmonad`.  Also, note that `export` only alters the environment of the current process _and_ child processes of the current process.  It has no effect on processes already running, such as another instance of terminal.

Answer (score 2):

#### What user/env is actually calling `xinit` when you start XQuartz?

Under Linux, this would be the user that you logged in as; I'd suspect that it's probably the same for Mac OS X.  As for the environment, whatever the current environment is when you run `xinit`, that will be the environment that `XQuartz` runs with, excepting changes to the environment done within one of the files that `XQuartz` reads when it starts up.

#### Where should I put `xmodmap` so that it's called once, and only once, when XQuartz is started?

To create your own custom map/table and store it in a configuration file, run:

```
xmodmap -pke > ~/.Xmodmap
```

Make the desired changes to `~/.Xmodmap` and then test the new configuration with:

```
xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

To active your custom table when starting Xorg, that is XQuartz, add the following to your `~/.xinitrc`

```
[ -s ~/.Xmodmap ] && xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap # you can also try using `[[ -s ~/.Xmodmap ]] && xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`
```

#### How do I get the LANG set once, and only once, as an environment variable when I start XQuartz (I need it for unicode support)

To set `LANG`, simply add one of the following to your `~/.xinitrc`

```
[[ -z "$LANG" ]] && LANG=<VALUE> # only sets LANG, if LANG is empty
LANG=<VALUE> # sets LANG regardless of whether it is or is not empty
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I'd had an `.xinitrc` already with similar code. I believe the problem is related somehow to the environment in which `xinit` is being called. If I run `whoami` in `.xinitrc` I get the correct user. However, if I look at `$ENV` within `.xinitrc` (by running `echo "$ENV" >> /Users/.../tmp.txt`) I see a different environment than when I finally land in the shell.

Comment: @weirdcanada have you checked the docs for XQuartz to see if it covers this kind of issue?